# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: design_config_grid_flat

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

Good morning,

I'm using magento 2.1.9 and yesterday I did a backup recovery, but now when I try to access to;

```
Content/Design/Configuration
```

the following error appears;

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myserver.design_config_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `design_config_grid_flat` AS `main_table`
```

How can I fix this error?

Thank you!

Comment: have you gone into the database to see if it's actually there? `show tables;`

Comment: I just checked my database and it's not there. So, how can i regenerate or create this table?

Comment: try running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile` in terminal - might add it again, if that doesn't work I'll post the table structure and data for you to copy

Comment: It doesn't add it again. Could you post the table structure and data please? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested in comment:

```
CREATE TABLE `design_config_grid_flat` (
    `entity_id`        int(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `store_website_id` int(11),
    `store_group_id`   int(11),
    `store_id`         int(11),
    `theme_theme_id`   varchar(255)
);
```

then the data:

```
INSERT INTO `design_config_grid_flat` (
    `store_website_id`, `store_group_id`, `store_id`
) VALUES
(null, null, null),
(1,    null, null),
(1,    1,    1);
```

This should do it - let me know if there are any issues (run in mysql^^)

Answer (score 0):

Create the missing table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `design_config_grid_flat` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `store_website_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store_website_id',
  `store_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store_group_id',
  `store_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store_id',
  `theme_theme_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Theme_theme_id',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_WEBSITE_ID` (`store_website_id`),
  KEY `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_GROUP_ID` (`store_group_id`),
  KEY `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_THEME_THEME_ID` (`theme_theme_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='design_config_grid_flat';
```

Then run the indexer:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```