# design_config_grid_flat' doesn't exist

Tags: database, attributes, product-attribute, reindex, magento-2.2.1

After **deleting an attribute and product attribute** I can't run

> php bin/magento cron:run

anymore. Also in the backend of Magento,

> backend>content>Design>configuration

I get the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'mcm2017_cd.design_config_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was: `` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `design_config_grid_flat` AS `main_table` ``

**Error Message on running `ssh: php bin/magento indexer:reset`**

> mcm2017@mcmtravels.com [~/mcmtours.at]# php bin/magento
>   indexer:reindex Design Config Grid indexer process unknown error:
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'mcm2017_cd.design_   config_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `design_config_grid_flat` (
>   `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
>   `store_website_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Store_website_id' ,
>   `store_group_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Store_group_id' ,
>   `store_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Store_id' ,
>   `theme_theme_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Theme_theme_id' ,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
>   INDEX `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_WEBSITE_ID` (`store_website_id`),
>   INDEX `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_GROUP_ID` (`store_group_id`),
>   INDEX `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
>   FULLTEXT `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_THEME_THEME_ID` (`theme_theme_id`)
> ) COMMENT='design_config_grid_flat' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
> Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
> Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> ```

I've **tried to create the table `design_config_grid_flat`** in the database, but without success.

Is that what I have to do? Some help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure but I found this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202002/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-design-config-grid-flat We are having the same problem why trying access backend>content>Design>configuration. Did you get yours fixed?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143100)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143100)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143100)

Comment: Has anyone fixed this?