# Magento 2.4.2 Installation with Sample Data errors

Tags: installation, magento2.4, sample-data, magento2.4.2

I can't proceed the Magento 2.4.2 sample data installation.

It's ***Nginx 1.19, PHP-FPM 7.4, MariaDB 10.4, Elasticsearch 7.11*** on Docker. Normal installation works without any problems.

The first time I run the installation it stops with the following error:

***In Mysql.php line 110:***

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of
> './magedb/catalog_category_product_index_store1_outdated' to
> './magedb/catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica' (errno: 194
> "Tablespace is missing for a table"),

***query was:***

`RENAME TABLE catalog_category_product_index_store1 TO catalog_category_product_index_store1_outdated,catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica` TO `catalog_category_product_index_store1,catalog_category_product_index_store1_outdated TO catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica`

***When I then just run it again, it stops with:***

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'magedb.design_config_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was: DELETE FROM
> `design_config_grid_flat`

Creating this table doesn't change anything... Does anyone have an idea to go through this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202002/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-design-config-grid-flat

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151779/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-db-design-config-grid

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing and using it locally then you can try creating a virtual host and installing your project in this new virtual. I followed these and it fixed the problem
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart